# Oauth2.0 Authorization Code Grant ClientId & Secret Confusion

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am trying to understand the various grant types offered by OAuth2.0. I have been reading up on it & there are a lot of resources that explain it in good details, like [this](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/example-flow/), [this](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/) & [this](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) to quote a few.

In case of authorization code grant type, from my understanding there are 2 steps.

**Step 1 - To get the authorization code itself**

So let's assume that the user opens the application, say `AwesomeApp` in their browser. This app has an option like say *Login with Facebook*, which the user chooses to go ahead with. This initiates a GET request made to the authorization server (of Facebook in our example) with the needed details in the query parameter, something like (taken from one of the resources linked above):

```
https://authorization-server-of-facebook.com/auth?response_type=code&
  client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=photos&state=1234zyx
```

Now I understand the meaning of each of those parameters (thanks to the resources again). I also understand that before the `AwesomeApp` could make this call, it must have registered with Facebook to receive a client ID & client secret (*through some means*).

Now once the user approves the request facebook's authorization server responds to the above request by redirecting the user's browser back to the redirect uri that was provided (in the above request) & with the authorization code.

**Step 2 - To exchange the authorization code for the actual access token**

Now `AwesomeApp` needs to exchange the authorization code received above for an access token. To do this `AwesomeApp` makes a POST request like the below:

```
POST https://api.authorization-server-of-facebook.com/token
  grant_type=authorization_code&
  code=AUTH_CODE_RECEIVED_IN_THE_ABOVE_STEP&
  redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&
  client_id=CLIENT_ID&
  client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
```

To the above request the authorization server of facebook returns back an access token, a refresh token an expiry time etc. etc.

Now my question is in the step 2 above. Shouldn't this POST be a backend call? Why? Because it requires the client secret to be sent across in the request as well. If it were to be done from the front end of `AwesomeApp`, it would easily be leaked to a spurious user. Isn't it?

So I was thinking, it should be something like once `AwesomeApp` receives the authorization code, the frontend of `AwesomeApp` should send this over to it's own backend & then `AwesomeApp`'s backend should make the above POST request, retrieve the access token (& other details) from the response of the above request & then pass it on to it's frontend. Is this not how it should be?

Now in most of the resources that I came across (including the above links), it discusses about `PKCE Extension` which talks about generating a dynamic client secret every time. But how is it any better if the POST (the one in the step 2) is still done from the front end itself? Also if this client secret is dynamically generated every time, it could be done by a spurious user as well, isn't it. I mean how would the authorization server validate that the client making the request was indeed the one that it had allowed? (In the client secret case it made sense, because the client secret was given to `AwesomeApp` by Facebook's authorization server. In this case it doesn't, because this secret is being generate by the client itself).

What am misunderstanding in all of the above?

As per the flow explained [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636), [image], how does the `code_verifier` prevent an adversary to play as a genuine app? Unlike with client secret, where the attacker would never be able to impersonate a genuine client (unless of course the client secret itself is somehow compromised), in this case, the attacker could simply send any `code_verifier`. Before even the token request & verification of the `code_verifier` & the final response comes into the picture, how would the authorization server even validate that the authorization request indeed came from a genuine client?

Answer (score 1):

You understand the authorization code flow correctly. In the original OAuth2 spec, the code flow was intended for [confidential clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) (i.e traditional web applications running on a server). Implicit flow was intended for applications running inside the browser like Single Page Applications. Implicit flow delivers the access token to the client directly via the redirect URI.

Now implicit flow was vulnerable to token leakage (referrer headers and server logs), so [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) was invented to use code flow for public clients also. It generates a hashed value from an identifier called `verifier` and sends it with the authorization request. When the client gets the code, it uses the verifier as the secret to prove to the authorization server it was the client that made the original authorization request (to which the user signed in).

Even though a malicious client can generate authorization request, the user needs to sign in and consent to the client getting an access token to access their data. If the user decides to trust the malicious client, there's nothing the protocol can do since the client does not have to authenticate itself.

Comment: rfc6749, states `The authorization code provides a few important security benefits, such as the ability to authenticate the client, as well as the transmission of the access token directly to the client without passing it through the resource owner's user-agent and potentially exposing it to others, including the resource owner.` **=>** meaning
authorization code flow is best when there's a backend involved & if it's done the way we were discussing in my question above. Continued in the next comment...

Comment: continued from the last comment... While PKCE makes sense only in case of implicit flow & SPAs (that do not have a backend). But in PKCE the hash of the `verifier` is generated by the client & sent to the authorization server. Then what do you mean with this 
`When the client gets the code, it uses the verifier as the secret to prove to the authorization server it was the client that made the original authorization request (to which the user signed in).` ?

Comment: PKCE is not meant to be used with implicit flow. Code flow + PKCE is meant to replace implicit flow. The problem is that a malicious client can get a token from the authorization server if they intercept the authorization code and use it before the legitimate client can. PKCE prevents this by requiring the verifier generated on the client when it sent the authorization request. Even if the malicious client got the challenge, there's no way it can get the verifier from it.

Comment: apologies, I'm still confused. To generate the authorization code, the first authorization request has to be made (in whose response the authorization code is sent back to the client). The `code_challenge` is sent with this request. Now, a malicious app could do the very same thing, because unless this request reaches the authorization server, the authorization server has no knowledge of the `code_challenge`. Right? So the whole verification of the `challenge_code` would now be done based on the malicious app's `challenge_code`. Isn't it? Am I still missing something?

Comment: Right, but between the first authorization request and the sending of the authorization code, the resource owner (user) has to sign in and consent to the application being granted access to their data on the resource server. Yes, if the malicious client application can trick the user into logging in and giving consent, it gets access. PKCE was invented to prevent a malicious client from stealing the code and getting a token with it without the user's sign in and consent.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks. @MvdD